# Recover files under a shared folder deleted by a guest Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, file-recovery

Within a guest VirtualBox Linux, I mistakenly deleted a folder shared with the host Windows. I stopped the deleting action during the process, but unfortunately, part of the files has already been deleted.

Is that possible that I could recover the files? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the folder was shared with Windows, any of the normal file recovery utilities working in Winodws, [as described by Microsoft itself](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-can-i-recover-deleted-files-with-shift-del/13b1eaad-d41a-4e77-91c5-f0bc9590de7d), will allow file recovery. Just make sure you turn your pc off immediately, to prevent accidental file overwrite, and use a live distro to boot it next time.

Comment: Many thanks. I have recovered most of the deleted files; I can see some recently created files have been lost (but not quit sure at current stage), quite satisfied though.